# How do you push_back into a 2D vector using "[ ]" container?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a problem with a function below :

```
vector<int> dynamicArray(int n, vector<vector<int>> queries) {
    int lastanswer=0;
    vector<int> lastanswerarr;
    int seq=0;
    vector< vector<int> > seqarr[n];
    int y;

    vector< vector<int> >::iterator row;
    vector<int>::iterator col;

    for(row= queries.begin();row!=queries.end();row++){
        for(col=row->begin();col!=row->end();col++){
            if(col[0]==1){
                seq=((col[1]^lastanswer) % n);
                seqarr[seq].push_back(col[2]);             //problem when pushing back
                
            }
            else{
                seq=((col[1]^lastanswer) % n);
                y= (col[2] % seqarr[seq].size());
                lastanswer=seqarr[seq][y];
                lastanswerarr.push_back(lastanswer);           //problem when pushing back
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return lastanswerarr;  }
```

I wanted to know is there something wrong with my declaration of vector< <vector > seqarr[n] ?

I tried using vector< <vector > seqarr(n) and it worked, but it still made me curious why i can't use "[ ]"?

Comment: `vector<vector<int>> seqarr[n];` is a non-standard declaration of an _array of vector of vectors_ (3D structure). `vector<vector<int>> seqarr(n);` is a _vector of vectors_ (2D structure) initialized by constructor argument `n`. You should learn more about array declarations and initialization.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. Appreciate it.